# BaseTest class doesn't initialize the Webdriver instance

Tags: selenium-webdriver, nullpointerexception, selenium-chromedriver, cucumber, bdd

I have gone through similar type Q&As, but couldn't figure out the issue in my code.

This is my BaseTest class
`

```
package com.supportiveTests;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import io.cucumber.java.After;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;

public class BaseTests {
    public static WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setUpDriver() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/main/resources/Drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    @After
    public void quitDriver() {
        this.driver.quit();
        System.out.println("done AfterTest");
    }
}
```

`

This is my stepDefinition class (LoginPageSteps)
`

```
package com.stepDefinitions;

import com.pageObjects.LoginPage;
import com.supportiveTests.BaseTests;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Test
public class LoginPageSteps extends BaseTests {
    LoginPage obj_login;

    @Given("User is on Google Home page")
    public void user_is_on_google_home_page() {
        BaseTests.driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.com/");
    }

    @Given("User is navigated to SwagLabs Login page")
    public void user_is_navigated_to_swag_labs_login_page() {
        BaseTests.driver.navigate().to("https://www.saucedemo.com/");
    }

    @When("^User enters valid (.*) and (.*)$")
    public void user_enters_valid_standard_user_and_secret_sauce(String username, String password) {
        obj_login = new LoginPage(driver);
        obj_login.enterUserName(username);
        obj_login.enterPassword(password);
    }

    @When("clicks on LOGIN button")
    public void clicks_on_login_button() {
        obj_login.clickOnLogin();
    }

    @Then("User is navigated to SwagLAbs Home page")
    public void user_is_navigated_to_swag_l_abs_home_page() throws InterruptedException {
        BaseTests.driver.getCurrentUrl().contains("https://www.saucedemo.com/inventory.html");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        BaseTests.driver.quit();
    }
}
```

`

This is my TestRunner class
`

```
package com.supportiveTests;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/Features",
        glue = {"com/stepDefinitions"},
        monochrome = true,
        plugin = {
                "pretty", "html:target/HTMLReports/report.html",
                "json:target/JSONReports/report.json",
                "junit:target/JUnitReports/report.xml"
        }
)
public class TestRunner {
}
```

`

This is my pageObject class (LoginPage)
`

```
package com.pageObjects;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class LoginPage {
    WebDriver driver;

    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    By txt_username = By.xpath("//input[@id='user-name']");
    By txt_password = By.xpath("//input[@id='password']");
    By btn_login = By.xpath("//input[@id='login-button']");

    public void enterUserName(String username){
        driver.findElement(txt_username).sendKeys(username);
    }

    public void enterPassword(String password){
        driver.findElement(txt_password).sendKeys(password);
    }

    public void clickOnLogin(){
        driver.findElement(btn_login).click();
    }


}
```

When the above TestRunner class is executed, I get this error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.navigate()" because "com.supportiveTests.BaseTests.driver" is null

    at com.stepDefinitions.LoginPageSteps.user_is_on_google_home_page(LoginPageSteps.java:16)
```

I went through the similar Q&As, where the solutions for driver initialization were provided, but couldn't figure out the issue. I am at basic level of Selenium testing framework, so appreciate any guidance on fixing this.

Comment: Can you explain why you think this would work?

Comment: 1. When TestRunner class is executed, it'd call stepDefinition class (LoginPageSteps), which has extended BaseTest class. 
2. Then, BaseTest class would initialize the WebDriver, and pass that value to stepDefinition class (LoginPageSteps)
3. But, I have a confusion of how that passing would conflict with WEbDriver instance, declared in pageObject class (LoginPage)

Comment: Why do you think step #2 would happen?

Comment: I tried calling Login function in BaseTest class (just for testing purpose), and it initialized the WebDriver instance, and tests got passed. So, I thought it'd perform in the same way when I extended it in stepDefinition class (LoginPageSteps). Could you pls point the error for me if you can, because I accept that I have erroneously implemented this logic here, and can't figure out the data passing. Thanks.

Comment: The error is in your understanding of the systems involved. Showing you how to do it right would not meaningfully help you. So next question: When calling the login function in the base test which systems and tools are you using? When running tests with the `TestRunner` which systems and tools are used?

Comment: In both scenarios, I ran TestRunner class to start test execution.
In the previous response, I included ONLY the Login function in BaseTest class just to test the initialization of WebDriver instance. (Here, I didn't extend BaseTest in stepDefinition class (LoginPageSteps)) 
Thus, used Cucumber, and TestNG annotations with POM implementation were there at both times.

Comment: So you are using Cucumber and TestNG annotations. When you use Cucumber the WebDriver isn't initialized (`null`). This means the code to do so didn't run. Why do you expect that code to run?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249137/discussion-between-dushan-anuradha-and-m-p-korstanje).

Comment: What I assume was since there is @Before hook, it'd invoke setUpDriver() in BaseTest class, then generate and  assign the value of driver instance to driver. Then, that value would pass over the required occurrences in the extended class. 

I referred to your answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69868702/cannot-invoke-org-openqa-selenium-webdriver-getstring-because-this-driver, and then I got java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at com.stepDefinitions.LoginPageSteps.user_is_on_google_home_page(LoginPageSteps.java:18) Checking that now.

Comment: Clearly the before hook is not getting triggered. Why do you expect it to be triggered?

Comment: I could solve the problem. Added this part to BaseTest class. 

@BeforeTest
    protected WebDriver getDriver(){
        if(driver == null){
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/main/resources/Drivers/chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();

        }
        return driver;
    }

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have added my work to GitHub: https://github.com/dushananuradha/Selenium_Testing_Framework_utilizing-PageFactory-BDD-Cucumber-TestNG .Will continue to develop this. Appreciate your comments, if possible. Thanks